# How to get previous and next value from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

Am using SQL Server 2005

For example if i select a particular hour (3rd) from a dropdownlist i want to fetch a corresponding staffs who are all free in that particular hour(3rd) as well as they must be free on either previous or nxt hour (2nd hour or 4th hour). How to i find this using select stmt.

Hence the staff who are all free on 2 hours continuosly they ll be displayed..

Comment: Can you please provide some details like your table design or anything ?

Comment: s the table time_table contains hour, day, subject and staffname. I want to know how to get the next or previous value from a db (SQL Server 2005) using select command

Comment: So you want to get the row which is just above or the row which is having free in the previous/next hour ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your logic correctly,Below answer will be helpful,

Take a look of it..

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9a557/4

A-Available
NA-Not Available